# External screen HDMI strange desktop problem

Tags: 18.04, sound, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've been using Ubuntu for about 6 years without any issue but recently I upgraded from Xubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and I am having a small problem with the external screen I usually use with an HDMI cable.

The problem is that whenever I start the system the desktop icons are rearranged so they occupy a small portion of the screen and, until I change the screen resolution forth and back, I cannot move the icons to any of the outer margins of the desktop; furthermore, whenever I change the resolution my HDMI audio will be gone for good, and only the laptop speakers will be recognised until I restart the computer.

I am running it on an Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller.

This is a very weird behaviour that did not happen before I upgraded to 18.04 and honestly I am not quite sure how to solve it. I can live without solving it but any help would be very much appreciated : )

Thanks in advance.